# Collection view not populating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I know there are other questions about this topic, but none of the solutions described there worked, so I'll try to explain my problem and hope someone can help me solve it.

I'm using a CollectionViewController to display an array of objects.
I thought that calling the methods to populate my arrays in the viewDidLoad method was the right way, but it isn't.

In short, I have some objects, downloaded remotely, those object have an url attribute, and I want to create an array of those urls that I'll need to use to populate my collectionView.

The problem is that I have not my array of objects available in the viewDidLoad, so I can't create my array of urls and go further.

This is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[self collectionView]setDataSource:self];
        [[self collectionView]setDelegate:self];
        [self.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_background"]];
        objectModel = [[ObjectModel alloc] init];
        self.availableObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.posterUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self createObjectArrayFromUrl:serverUrl intoArray:self.availableObjectsArray];
        //FIRST TRY NSMutableArray *postersUrlSection1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self posterUrlsFromObjects:self.availableObjectsArray]];
     //SECOND TRY (AFTER ALLOC AND INIT)  postersUrlSection1 = [self posterUrlsFromObjects:self.availableMoviesArray];
// [[self collectionView] reloadData]; ADDED AS PART OF THE SOLUTION BUT DIDN'T SOLVE THE ISSUE
                NSLog(@"Array OBJECTS populated? %@", self.availableMoviesArray);
                NSLog(@"Array URLS populated? %@", postersUrlSection1);

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

        // Register cell classes
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //    [self.collectionView reloadData]; ADDED AS A SOLUTION BUT NOT SOLVING MY ISSUE
}
```

I managed to get the main object array populated: even if it doesn't show anything in the log in the viewDidLoad, it somehow loads the objects if I want to do something with them in the

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

method, but obviously if I need it right away (in the viewDidLoad for example), it doesn't get populated.
How do I get it populated in the viewDidLoad, or at least how can I use my objectsArray before the three main collectionViewController methods get called?
I need this because I have to do this:

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[self.posterUrls objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

EDIT1:

I use this method to populate my url arrays:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) posterUrlsFromObjects: (NSMutableArray *) objectsArray{
Object *object = [[object alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *posterUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *placeholder = [NSURL URLWithString:@"placeholder"];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [objectsArray count]; ++index) {
    object = [objectsArray objectAtIndex:index];
    if (object.posterURL != nil)
        [posterUrls addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:object.posterURL]];
    else
        [posterUrls addObject:placeholder];
}
return posterUrls;}
```

Even by adding a

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

before the return, it doesn't get the array populated as it should be.

EDIT2:
Yes I'm populating my main object array in an asynchronous way.

```
    - (void) createObjectArrayFromUrl: (NSString *) url intoArray: (NSMutableArray *) objectArray{
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  if(error) {
                                      NSLog(@"Error");
                                  }
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                      NSMutableDictionary *jsonDataDictionary = [objectModel getRemoteJsonDataFromUrl:url];
                                      [movieArray removeAllObjects];
                                      [movieArray addObjectsFromArray:[objectModel arrayFromDictionary:jsonDataDictionary]];
                                      [[self collectionView] reloadData];

                                  });
                              }];
[task resume];
}
```

EDIT3:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2; //LOG RETURNS 2
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.availableMoviesArray count];   //LOG RETURNS 0
  // WHAT I WANTED TO DO  return [[self.posterUrls objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

The method `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` gets called.

Comment: My guess is that you are populating your array in a asychronous way, since you said "I managed to get the main object array populated: even if it doesn't show anything in the log in the viewDidLoad". Could you show the code of `createObjectArrayFromUrl:intoArray:`?

Comment: I edited my question, thanks for your time.

Comment: In `createObjectArrayFromUrl:intoArray:`, `movieArray` is populated. But you don't care about it, since in `collectionView: numberOfItemsInSection:` you look for `posterUrls`, which is just initialized with none object.

Comment: @Larme Sorry, that posterUrls is a leftover: I created 2 different arrays (let's call them section1 and section2) that I want to populate with the values of a certain attribute of the objects in objectsArray (and that's my issue, can't figure out how to do it). Then I want to merge those arrays in one array, that "posterUrls" so that I can create the 2 different sections of my collectionView

Comment: Could you show the code of `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:`, put a log of returned values of `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:`  and `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` and put a log into `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to see if it's called?

Comment: @Larme Done, please take a look.

Comment: What's `movieArray`? Where is it init? Your code is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Initially collectionview methods delegate and datasource method will getcalled . You can call "collectionview reloadData" to call the delegate calls again. If you populate your Array at "methodA" means , . Once array gets ready call [self.collectionview reloadData]. This will trigger all the delegate and datasource methods again.

```
    -(void)populateArray 
   {
   [arrayObject addObject:@"valueOne"];
    [arrayObject addObject:@"valueTwo"];
   [arrayObject addObject :@"valuethree"];
   [arrayObject addObject:@"valueFour"];
   [self.collectionview reloadData];

   }
```